# How to call a function with parameters and user console input in C++?

Tags: c++, function, console

This is C++ console snippet.

I wish to call a fonction holding parameters amongst several function depending on user input.

For example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void Add (int x, int y)
    {
        cout << x + y << endl;
    }

void Subs (int x, int y)
    {
        cout << x - y << endl;
    }


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Variable initialization
    char calc_type;
    int x;
    int y;

    // Console input
    cout << "Add or Substract (a or s)?" << endl;
    cin >> calc_type;
    cout << "1st number" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "2nd number" << endl;
    inc >> y;

    if (calc_type == "a")
    {
        Add(x, y);
    }
    else
    {
        Subs(x, y);
    }

return 0;

}
```

But in writing this I am returned error messages like the followings:

**error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'**

**There is no context in which this conversion is possible**

**error C2040: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char [2]'**

How can I cope with this problem (maybe references or pointers are preferred???)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calc_type` is a `char` variable. The constant "a" is a string. In C, char constants are in single quotes, not in double ones. So rephrase as:

```
if (calc_type == 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotation marks for character literals.

```
if (calc_type == "a")
```

The double quotation marks here mean that `"a"` is a string literal, which means it has the type `const char[2]` (`{'a', '\0'}`). `calc_type` is a `char`, so the types don't match. `'a'`, on the other hand, has a character type, which you can compare fine.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant:

```
calc_type == 'a'
```

instead of

```
calc_type == "a"
```

since `calc_type` is a `char` and `"a"` is a `const char*`?

Comment: To nitpick, string literals aren't pointers.